# XML serialization wont work

Tags: c#

Im tryng to write down the attributes of my object to a xml file... but its not working.

The method :

```
public void Save(string fileName)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);

    new XmlSerializer(typeof(Character)).Serialize(stream, this);
    stream.Close();
}
```

The main :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var char1 = new Character();
        char1.setDexterity(20);
        char1.Save("CharData.xml");
    }
}
```

I also tried with `char1.save(@"C:\Users\Avell B155\Desktop\CharData.xml");`

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? What happens when you try?

Comment: Define "Not working". Is it throwing an exception? If so, what is the exception? Or does it just do nothing?

Comment: Please show your `Character` class as well.

Comment: No errors, but it doesnt write anything on the CharData.xml  file

Comment: could you tell us what exactly isn't working? I guess the Save method is part of the Character class which is written by you?

Comment: I think you need to post a snippet of how your "Character" class looks like, maybe its not tagged as "Serializable"

Comment: is the file beeing created if it doesn't exist?

Comment: http://dontpad.com/kmx2 here is the complete char class

Comment: XML Serialization works by serializing public **properties** and you don't have any public properties in the class, so it won't save anything.

Comment: Moreover, the BCL XML serializer works by serializing **public** properties, which you don't have any of. Instead of having a bunch of setter and getter methods, just use properties.

Comment: Ron and Asad are right. From [this MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx): "The Serialize method converts the public fields and read/write properties of an object into XML. It does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or read-only properties. To serialize all of an object's fields and properties, both public and private, use the BinaryFormatter."

Comment: omg, thanks guys, ye i set them to public and it now works. god dammit